# jQuery Mobile Custom Theme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm a beginner creating an app through jQuery Mobile, i am trying to incorporate a custom theme through theme roller and it prompted me to use these lines of code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
```

I have already put the themes folder in the apps folder however I am trying to figure out how to include these lines within this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function(){
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
    });
    </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

All while not changing the layout and current look. The end goal is to figure out how to change the background and button colors on my app. Thank you!

Comment: You need to include the stylesheet links underneath the jquery mobile css stylesheet

Comment: The color still has not changed even after inserting it there.